# Using JQuery to Generate Nested Objects in One Form in Rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

Using Rails 4, and based on [Railscast #197](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2) I'm trying to create both parent and child objects using a single form dynamically via Javascript.  I've modified Ryan Bate's code in his application helper (on the same page as the railscast episode) so that I can create both a parent object (BudgetSegment) and child object (BudgetRatio) in one form.

I'd like someone to take a look at my `link_to_add_fields` method below and tell me what is wrong, as it is not working, AND to tell me if it is the culprit for the feature not working.  Could it be that you can't nest the `builder.fields.for`in the `f.fields_for` block below? Here is the relevant code in `application_helper.rb`:

```
def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association, nested_association, locals={})
    new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
    nested_new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.reflect_on_association(nested_association).klass.new

    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|
        builder.fields_for(nested_association, nested_new_object, :child_index => "new_#{nested_association}") do |nested_builder|
            render(association.to_s.singularize + "_row", locals.merge!(:ff => builder, :fff => nested_builder))
        end
    end
    link_to_function(name, "add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{nested_association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")")
end
```

Here is my js file:

```
function add_fields(link, association, nested_association, content) {
  var new_id = new Date().getTime();
  var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g")
  var regexp2 = new RegExp("new_" + nested_association, "g")
  $(link).parent().parent().parent().before().child(content.replace(regexp, new_id).replace(regexp2, new_id);
}
```

Both BudgetSegment and BudgetRatio are on the same row of a table.  the goal is to allow the user to dynamically create a new row of text fields upon clicking an add button.  This row would concurrently create both a BudgetSegment text field in the first column and an indeterminate number of BudgetRatio text fields in the columns to the right(for the Javascript method, I'm only assuming one BudgetRatio is created, although as you will see in the budget_source_controller, there are five BudgetRatios created initially).

This `link_to_add_fields` code should be generating the following partial `_budget_segment_row.html.erb` below:

```
<tr  class="table-financial">
    <td><%= ff.text_field :max, :id => "form-currency", :class => "form-control",  :placeholder => '"$1,000,000"', :required => :true %>
    </td>

        <%= ff.fields_for :budget_ratios do |fff| %>     
        <td><%= fff.text_field 'box_value', :class => "form-control", :placeholder => 'e.g., "0.75"' %></td>
        <td><%= fff.text_field 'pa_value', :id => "pa-value", :class => "form-control", :placeholder => 'e.g., "0.75"' %></td>
        <% end %>    
</tr>
```

When I debug, the `fields`variable defined in `link_to_add_fields` at the top does not return the child (BudgetRatio), only the parent (BudgetSegment).  Below is what `fields` returns:

```
"<tr  class=\"table-financial\">\n\t<td><input class=\"form-control\" id=\"form-currency\" name=\"budget_source[budget_segments_attributes][new_budget_segments][max]\" placeholder=\"&quot;$1,000,000&quot;\" required=\"required\" type=\"text\" />\n\t</td>\n\t\t\n\t\t</tr>"
```

As you can see, anything in the BudgetRatio block is missing.

Here is my model structure (relevant parts included only):

```
class BudgetSource < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :budget_segments
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :budget_segments
end

class BudgetSegment < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :budget_ratios
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :budget_ratios
end

class BudgetRatio < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :budget_segment
end
```

Below is `new.html.erb` for BudgetSource (a few irrelevant parts omitted):

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="info-box">

    <%= form_for @budget_source, :method => :post, :url => budget_sources_path do |f| %>

    <%= render 'tag_menu_new', :f => f %>    

    <%= f.fields_for :budget_segments do |ff| %>  
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-condensed table-hover">
        <tr class="table-sources-heading">
          <th rowspan="2">Budget Segment Maximum</th>
          <% scenarios.each do |s| %>
          <th colspan="2"><%= s.name %></th>
          <% end %>
          <th rowspan="2">add</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-sources-heading">
          <% scenarios.each do |s| %>
          <th><%= "Box Ratio" %></th>
          <th><%= "P&A Ratio" %></th>
          <% end %>
        </tr>
        <%= render 'budget_segment_row', {f: f, ff: ff} %>
        <tr>
          <td><div class="btn btn-default"><%= link_to_add_fields "Add Row", f, :budget_segments, :budget_ratios, :f => f %></td>
        </tr>

      </table>

    </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'>
  <%= f.submit 'Save', :class => "btn btn-success" %>
</div>
 </div>
</div>
    <% end %>
    </div>
```

Below is `budget_sources_controller.rb`:

```
class BudgetSourcesController < ApplicationController  
  include ApplicationHelper
  require 'debugger'

  def new
    @budget_source = BudgetSource.new
    2.times { @budget_source.budget_sources_genres.build }
    @budget_segment = @budget_source.budget_segments.build
    scenarios.count.times { @budget_segment.budget_ratios.build }
    render 'budget_sources/new'
  end

  def create
    @budget_source = BudgetSource.create(budget_source_params)
    @budget_source.update(:user_id => current_user.id)
    @budget_source.budget_segments.order(:id).each do |bs|
      bs.budget_ratios.order(:id).each_with_index do |br, i|
        br.update(scenario_id: i+1)
      end
    end
    render 'show'
  end

  def show
    @budget_source = BudgetSource.find(params[:id])
    render 'show'
  end


    private

  def budget_source_params
    params.require(:budget_source).permit(:id, :user_id, :name, :description, :territory_id, budget_sources_genres_attributes: [:id, :genre_id, :budget_source_id], budget_segments_attributes: [:id, :max, budget_ratios_attributes: [:id, :box_value, :pa_value, :budget_segment_id, :scenario_id]])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this wasn't quite the solution I wanted (I really wanted to know why you're not able to nest an object using builder), my quick fix was:

Rather than nesting a `f.fields_for` method inside a `fields_for do |f|` block (as is conventional in views), I created a nested object by using the `[object].object.association.build`  method.

You'll note a new line starting with `array` because I wanted to create a defined number of objects at the same time, so I passed an `iterator` variable into the method that is basically just a integer.  Here's my revised `link_to_add_fields` code:

```
def add_row(name, f, association, nested_association, iterator)
  new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
  fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: "new_#{association}") do |bs|
    array = eval("iterator.map {bs.object.#{nested_association}.build}")
    render(association.to_s.singularize + "_row", {f: f, ff: bs, fff: array})  
  end      
  link_to_function(name, "add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this might not solve your problem, but it'll help with readability at least. Try doing this:

```
new_object = f.const_get(association).new
nested_new_object = f.const_get(nested_association).new
# new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
# nested_new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.reflect_on_association(nested_association).klass.new
```

However, i think what might be the issue is you are passing in fff: fff

```
locals.merge!(:ff => builder, :fff => nested_builder))
```

and the only place you're using `fff` that I can see is inside this block:

```
    <%= ff.fields_for :budget_ratios do |fff| %>     
    <td><%= fff.text_field 'box_value', :class => "form-control", :placeholder => 'e.g., "0.75"' %></td>
    <td><%= fff.text_field 'pa_value', :id => "pa-value", :class => "form-control", :placeholder => 'e.g., "0.75"' %></td>
    <% end %>
```

but as you know, the fff inside the block isn't the `fff` that youre passing. Might not be the error, but looks like it could be an oversight. Maybe you meant to merge in `f` and `ff`

Also, here's an example of a triple nested form that added new items to an even in a table. Might help to look at:

Here's the javascript we used to add/remove items.

https://github.com/alukima/TooManyChips/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/add_item.js

events' create view:
https://github.com/alukima/TooManyChips/blob/master/app/views/events/_create_event_form.html.erb

and partial for add_items at the bottom, which had the 3rd nesting in it.
https://github.com/alukima/TooManyChips/blob/master/app/views/event_items/_create_event_items_form.html.erb

Comment: Thanks for delving into the code, unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem. The partial should generate 'fff' itself, however, those objects, because they were not originally built in the controller, have to be built separately. that's why I create them in the method and try to push them as locals.